# Oracle forms to XML frmf2xml, missing properties

Tags: xml, oracle, oracle11g, converters, oracleforms

I'm converting Oracle forms to XML but unfortunately there are items missing in the XML that are on the property palette.

I have narrowed down the issue to the fact that any item on the property palette that has a green dot next to it will not be in the XML items set of properties.

The image below shows an example of this. In this case the list elements will be missing. If I hit the inherit button (which is circled in the image) the green dot will disappear and the list elements will appear in the XML.
[image]

I have thousands of forms with tens of thousands of items so doing this manually is not really a viable option.

Is it possible to include an option when using the frmf2xml tool to include these items or any other ideas I could use to solve my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are using `frmf2xml`, what option are specifying for `DUMP`?

From the documents:

> DUMP=ALL/OVERRIDEN    If DUMP=ALL, the tool dumps all properties. If
>   DUMP=OVERRIDEN, the tool dumps only those properties that are
>   overriden.

Source:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14373_01/migrate.32/e13368/appmgr_forms.htm#CHDFJHFD

Comment: DUMP=ALL helped provide a lot better xml... Thanks